# Populate HTML Form with Ajax, PHP, and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am create some sort of form which is supposed to be populated using ajax after select box will be selected. I need your advice and suggestiong in better of doing it;

Here is my script;

```
`[HTML] AND [AJAX]`

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function showReportWrite(str)
            {
            if (str.length==0)
            { 
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("report_write").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
            </script>

<div id="report_write"></div>
```

`[PHP]`

```
if($form_name == 'form_report1'){
        //action
    }
    if($form_name == 'form_report2'){
        //action
    }
    if($form_name == 'form_report3'){
        //action
    }

    echo '<div id="accordion">';


    echo '<h3><a href="#">Users Details</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <form class="form" name="form_report1">
                        <fieldset>
                        <legend>Client Details:</legend>    
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="10">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Client Name</b></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Date</b></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>    

                        <fieldset>
                        <legend>Candidate Details:</legend>    
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="10">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Date of Birth</b></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>ID or Passport No.</b></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Country</b></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Address</b></td>
                                    <td><textarea name="text"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Contact Details</b></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" id="sendbutton" name="sendbutton"/>
                    </form>
                </div>';
```

The idea is something like this, Once user select the select box, ajax will request for php file where based on the condition which is `form_report1` will do some action and echo the html form.

I am wondering whether there are some other ways  of  doing it some API may be which can boost may work. I need your suggest as expert. Because, I did not find any other option in the web. Thanks

Comment: Really, you didn't find anything to help you on the web?  What about all of those **Related** questions on the right?

Comment: Because, most of them they have bug, and they don't give that much details except of their problem

Comment: I am not asking to do something for me. I am showing the way I am going to achieve my gol. I wanto to know whether the way I am going to do is best way or there some other ways of doing it

Comment: I want from some who has done something  like may be he can suggest me better way

Comment: Fair enough; but I don't think that's what SO is for.  Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I agree with @eggyal, SO is a Q&A site, so you ask a **question** and then get answers in return. When I'm reading your Q and it says 'I need your advice...' I'm put off because I get a feeling I'll have to wade through pages and pages of code just to find out what it actually is you're trying to solve/what your question is. So, if you're looking for some good responses, try formulating a good, straight question and point out what you are trying to do (actually, this is all in the FAQ, but still...)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd be using jQuery or MooTools to do the ajax calls. They have cross browser implementations for this, the kind of thing you are trying to do in all the most part in the first piece of script you posted.

These frameworks also make it easy to use event handlers, which I'm missing for your select box.

Your PHP also seems incomplete, with the `$form_name` variable apparently coming out of nowhere. What determines this? How are you handling the `GET` parameters you are sending with your ajax call? Besides, why aren't you `POST`-ing your form, because a form basically *exists* to be posted.

So, if you want to improve, get jQuery or MooTools (or another javascript framework, but these are two of the most widely used), read up on these, and also read up on handling ajax calls in your PHP. And there really is *plenty* of that stuff on the web.